# MySQLi PHP: Check if SQL INSERT query was fully successful using MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have this big function that gets a lot of different data and insert it into multiple tables.. Not all the data is always available so not all the SQL INSERT queries are successful. I need to check which SQL INSERT query was fully successful and which wasn't to the do something with this data (like inserting into a log table or similar).

Just to give you an example of how I think it can be done:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO data_table (ID, column1, column2) VALUES(?, ?, ?)';

if ($stmt->prepare($sql)) {
    $stmt->bind_param('iss', $varID, $var1, $var2);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $success == TRUE;   //or something like that
    }
}
```

I'm not completely sure this is the best way and if its always really show if the data was inserted into the table...
Any suggestions??

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the PHP Manual on **[`mysqli_stmt::execute`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php):**

> `mysqli_stmt::execute` --
>   `mysqli_stmt_execute` — *Executes a
>   prepared Query*
>
> **Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on
>   failure.**

---

```
if ($stmt->execute()) { // exactly like this!
    $success = true;
}
```

You're doing it right... What's your dilemma?

Comment: Err, no, it should read `$success = TRUE;` since you don't want to test for equality but want to assign a value to the $success variable.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you can use [`mysqli_stmt->affected_rows`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php) to return the number of rows inserted (or changed or deleted).